# How to increment hits/visit on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, cookies

I have a blog web site which on every page has a that shows total number of visits to that page. Which are calculated that after every time page loads a asynchronous call is sent to the server which increments the hit for the post to `+1`.

But the issue is, if I keep refreshing the page it keeps increasing the counter. But i want to make it a little transparent and increase only for unique visitors.

Should I record the `IP`s of last 10 or 25 visitors and check if the visitor came recently or not.

Or should I store cookies and read if the cookie exists rather than increment or not?

Comment: I would go for the cookie since it's more easy and most people don't care about a cookie remembering if they are a unique visitor or not.

Answer (score 0):

This greatly depends on how accurate you want your data to be. If it should be just a simple little counter, setting a cookie will do the trick. Please note that this is most easily fakeable, since you can just come back after deleting the cookie.

Storing the IP addresses is easily fakeable aswell and it includes extra load to your database. Its also a problem regarding several users behind a single router, sharing the same IP address.

The most sofisticated approach i guess would be to use an analytics tool like http://piwik.org/ and use its API to get the number of unique users on a specific page. Could be somewhat slow and a slight overkill depending on what you are planning to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a cookie which expires after a day, or whenever you want, but also give the user the option to deactivate cookies, in this case you would need to record the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Try soomething similar to the code below.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Applcation object in JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    Integer hitsCount = 
      (Integer)application.getAttribute("hitCounter");
    if( hitsCount ==null || hitsCount == 0 ){
       /* First visit */
       out.println("Welcome to my website!");
       hitsCount = 1;
    }else{
       /* return visit */
       out.println("Welcome back to my website!");
       hitsCount += 1;
    }
    application.setAttribute("hitCounter", hitsCount);
%>
<center>
<p>Total number of visits: <%= hitsCount%></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```